# sp_prepare and sp_execute

Tags: database, sql-server-2005

I've been consulting google for some time now, but it hasn't been able to give me a satisfactory answer...

In a SQL Server 2005 trace, I've got lots of "exec sp_execute" statements. I know they are connected to a corresponding "exec sp_prepare" statement which specifies the actual SQL.

But...

**One:** Is it possible to find out the SQL behind the sp_execute without finding the sp_prepare?

**Two:** What type of construct would typically hide behind the sp_execute? That is, is it a stored procedure? Is it just a string in code? Or what?

**Three:** Should I fear bad performance seeing these in the trace?

Any input is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_query_plan(PlanHandle)
```

to generate an xml document that indicates what sql sp_execute is using.

Answer (score 3):

Those are API Server Cursors, most probably used by an old (or not so old, but badly developed) application.

99% of the times, cursors affect performance on your server. Disk and network I/O are the potential victims.

Read [this](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/joe_chang/archive/2010/11/19/api-server-cursors-and-related-system-cursor-stored-procedures.aspx), it helped me understanding how server side cursors work.

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, but I recently had an application with bad performance executing sp_prepare and sp_execute.

**One**: Answered before

**Two**: It could be anything, stored procedures, any valid sql query basically.

**Three**: I had problems with SQL Server failing to generate good execution plans when the application was using sp_prepare. Basically, SQL Server analyzes the incoming parameters to generate a good execution plan, but with sp_prepare no values for the parameters are supplied, since they are only added when executing sp_execute. So in the mean time, SQL Server applies generic costs for different operators and might very well generate a suboptimal plan.

If you look at your reads/cpu-usage for your traces, you should be able to determine if your queries are behaving badly or as expected.

Also see http://blogs.infosupport.com/speeding-up-ssis-literally